# Spring Data. Search using many fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a question about search in Spring Data JPA. I'm trying to write something like this:

```
List<UserDbo> findbyFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String LastName)
```

But I want that the values that this request takes may be empty.

For example:

If you do search in **social network**, you can put a lot of information, like : Country, City, School, firstName and you find someone, using this parameters, but also you can put only one or two parameters, like *firtName* and *country* and your query still working.

So, I want to create a query method where parametres can be **optional empty**.
In my code example, I want to find by **FirsName and Lastname**, or only by **FirstaName** or only by **LastName**.

I hope I described it clearly.

Comment: In General i need to search by incoming UserDto which can have a different set of parameters

Comment: Maybe you want something like Query By Example? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example

Answer (score 0):

This will search first and lastname together not seperately

Let's say in your database we have

firstname - lastname

john         wick

john         king

If you search findbyFirstNameAndLastName("john","");

you get nothing because query will be like where firstname=="john" AND lastname=="wick"

If you want it separately you can do :

```
List<UserDbo> findbyFirstName(String firstName);
List<UserDbo> findbyLastName(String lastName);
```

You can do null checks of those strings and search by seperately

Comment: yes, this simple querys is good, but in my case a have a lot of parametres in incoming Dto, like : Name, address, Shool and other things. So i want to search using all the parameters that came to me. In case when you have only FirstName and LastName it's easy to null check and choose one of request, but how to do this if you have a lot of parametres? In General i need to search by incoming UserDto which can have a different set of parameters

Comment: Ohh I see now,  did you try with "or"  something like:

findByUserNameOrLastname you can extend it or city or school... etc etc.

now our query will be 

where firstname=="john" or lastname=="wick" or..

Comment: i'm trying use Or, but if i search by ("john", "wick") i will get:
john wick and
john king

Comment: "The additional interface carries methods that allow you to execute Specifications in a variety of ways.

For example, the findAll method will return all entities that match the specification:

List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);"


I searched google findBy method from JPA what is it for, I think you should look at this link :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

In 2.4 Specifications part.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is only about these 2 fields (or a few additional fields), you can use a native query:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT user FROM UserDbo user "
             + " WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR user.firstName = :firstName)
             + " AND   (:lastName  IS NULL OR user.lastName  = :lastName)
      )       
List<UserDbo> find(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

If your need is much larger or evolving constantly, and you need to build your query dynamically based on your input criteria, I suggest investigating [spring-boot-starter-data-search](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search).

You can find a demo for jpa [here](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search-jpa-demo)

---

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of spring-boot-starter-data-search*